# Security level on SP13

Tags: 2013, security

This is the scenario:

I have a SP13 in which I'm deploying a File Server, so I created one web application and inside of it one Site Collection for each department.

I give Full Control access to a user on his SC but he gets for the whole WA, and if I give the user Read access for the WA and Full Control access on his SC he can't access anything.

How can I grant the correct permissions?

Comment: Are you sure you have created multiple Site Collections and not multiple sites under the same Site Collection?

Comment: Hi Vardhaman, I tried to create multiple sites under the same Site Collection, but can't create the security levels for each Site Collection, every user has access to all the others Site Collections, and that's my point...